# replace names of all directiories and files in C#

Tags: c#, replace, directory, filenames

This question had asked for PowerShell before. I want to do this in C#.
I have a directory on my desktop. The directories name is "rename".

```
C:\Users\dell\Desktop\rename
```

And "rename" folder contains "a_b", "b_c", "c_d", "d_e" folders.
I want to replace "_" with "-" characters.
In other words, folders' new names will be "a-b", "b-c", "c-d", "d-e"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's the question? And what have you tried?

Comment: i am new at c#. I just tried that in PowerShell. However, I want to do  that with C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a `DirectoryInfo` object representing the `rename` folder, iterate through its subfolders, and use `String.Replace` to replace `_` with `-`:

```
var parent = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\dell\Desktop\rename");

foreach (var child in parent.GetDirectories()) {
    var newName = child.FullPath.Replace('_', '-');

    if (newName != child.FullPath) {
        child.MoveTo(newName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Rename" files like this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/435a2692-6161-4039-bfa9-5e6211d90c49/

And you can do `filename.Replace('_', '-')` on each filename to replace underscores with hyphens.

Comment: Ok. I saw this. But i don't want to write file path again and again. I want to change all files' names in path "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\rename" .